# Are experience-sharing oriented questions welcome?

Tags: discussion, scope

As this kind of question could appear, I'm asking to know how do we handle them.

- Are experience-sharing oriented questions welcome on our site?
  *(i.e. "How did you handle your veg*n transition with your relatives?", "Was avoiding meat difficult at the beginning?", etc.)*

In my humble opinion, I think those questions could be too broad and opinion-based but could also provide useful information to the OP who can pick ideas from answers to apply it to its own situation.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: It is better to raise these issues with actual examples of questions you find pervasive or concerning on this site rather than trying to work up a sweeping declaration about a vague question-type that **everyone is going to interpret differently.**

Comment: @RobertCartaino I wanted to add one or two in my post, but I thought they could not be good examples of want I mean. I'll edit as soon as I got one.

Comment: Niitaki, Then as a side note, we're generally trying to avoid these hypotheticial/forced rules discussions before a problem turns up on the actual site.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'll keep that in mind. I've added two examples. Is it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, some of them are welcome.

However, let's use common sense to single out those can be answered in a way helpful to other people.

Let's **close** questions of this type that...

- ...are only helpful to the OP and noone else.
- ...are unclear e.g. because they don't relate to a common experience many vegetarians share.
- ...invite too many completely different answers.

Let's **keep** questions of this type that...

- ...refer to situations that many vegetarians might find themselves in.

Good examples for such questions:

- [How can I communicate ideas about vegetarianism or veganism to others without appearing like I am imposing it on them?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/269/how-can-i-communicate-ideas-about-vegetarianism-or-veganism-to-others-without-ap)

(Feel free to add bullet points.)